# Representing FP relations using witnesses

Tags: complexity-theory

> Let a relation $R$ be *A-polynomial* if there is a polynomial $p$ and a polytime algorithm $A$ such that for each $x$:
>
> 1. If $(x,y) \in R$ then there is a witness $w$ of length at most $p(|x|)$ such that $A(x,w) = y$.
> 2. For each $w$ such that $A(x,w)$ halts, we have $(x,A(x,w)) \in R$.
>
> Prove or disprove: Each $R$ in FP is A-polynomial.

My attempt: I think the statement is incorrect, and so I'm looking for a counterexample. Let $R$ be a relation in FP where the algorithm $A$ helps us decide the undecidable halting problem. I thought maybe about $R= \left\{0,1\right\}^*\times \left\{0,1\right\}^*$, but perhaps there is a simpler counterexample?

Comment: Please proof-read the post. A lot of places don't make sense. Explain what $PF$ and $\bot$ are.

Comment: $\bot$ is when the algorithm halt

Comment: I did my best to understand your suggested solution, but the first sentence still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Which sentence?

Comment: @Xavi "Let  be a relation in FP where the algorithm  helps us decide the undecidable halting problem."

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I try to find a relation that is in $PF$ and also don't have a polytime algorithm $A$ to disprove it. Maybe do you have a simpler counterexample?

Comment: Any reason for the bounty/ why the current answer was not satisfying?

Comment: @Ariel How do you prove that the relation is in $FP$? And can you explain why it's not A-Polynomial, I don't get it..

Comment: Write down the definition of an FP relation. Do you understand why an A polynomial relation can't have too many pairs of the form $(x,y_1),...(x,y_n)$ ?

Comment: @Ariel Ok, I understand why the relation isn't A-Polynomial, but how do you know that it's in $FP$, we need a polytime alogorithm that solves the relation, I don't get it..

Comment: How can you solve a relation that contains all possible pairs? think of a very simple algorithm

Comment: @Ariel Which algorithm?

Comment: @ArielCan you edit it in your answer and write it down? I'm sorry I'm new in this topic and it's a bit hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

An $A$-polynomial relation can't have two many pairs agreeing on the first coordinate. Namely for any $x$ there can be at most $2^{p(x)}$ $y$'s such that $(x,y)\in R$. This shows that the simple relation $R=\{0,1\}^*\times\{0,1\}^*$ is in FP but not A-polynomial.

Comment: You mean in $PF$? Maybe do you have a good counterexample?

Comment: FP is the more common name, check the zoo, https://complexityzoo.net/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp. Counterexample for what?

Comment: That $\forall R \in PF$ is "A-Polynomial"

Comment: The relation R in my answer is such an example